# Problema para hacer un IF en LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Cuando un cliente tiene en el campo EXENTO una 'E' debe pasar de grabado a exento y descuento G a descuento E 
MV_VR_GRABADO -> MV_VR_EXENTO 
MV_VR_DSCTO_G -> MV_VR_DSCTO_E
pero no me esta funcionando, podría ser con un IF o que otra forma me podrían recomendar para que funcione y me guarde en los campos correctos los valores que son numéricos osea exento es que no se le cobra IVA

```
$nuevoPedidoGenERP  = tbPedidosGenERP::create(
            array(
                'MV_TIPO'           => $tipoDocERP, 
                'MV_TIPOF'          => $tipoDocERP, 
                'MV_NUM'            => $numeroPedidoERP, 
                'MV_FACTURA'        => $numeroPedidoERP, 
                'MV_FCH'            => $fechaHoy, 
                'MV_FCH_LLEGA'      => $fechaHoy,
                'MV_FCH_VENCE'      => date('Ymd', strtotime($fechaHoy . ' + ' . ($condpago->dias  + 1) . ' days')),
                'MV_COD'            => $nitCliente,
                'MV_SEQK'           => $pedidoActual->tercero->sec,
                'MV_ZONA'           => $zonaCliente,
                'MV_VENDED'         => $pedidoActual->codvendedor,
                'MV_FORMA_PAGO'     => $pedidoActual->condpago,
                'MV_NOM_FP'         => $condpago->descripcion,
                'MV_PLAZO_1'        => $condpago->dias,
                /*'MV_DSCTO_1'        => $condpago->dscto,*/
                /* Cuando es 'E' pasar de grabado a exento y descuento G a descuento E */
                /* MV_VR_GRABADO -> MV_VR_EXENTO */
                /* MV_VR_DSCTO_G -> MV_VR_DSCTO_E */
                'MV_VR_DSCTO_G'     => round($totalDscto, 0),
                // exento
                'MV_VR_DSCTO_E'     => 0,
                'MV_IVA'            => 'S',
                'MV_VALOR'          => $totalBrutoDoc, 
                'MV_VR_GRAVADO'     => $totalBrutoDoc, 
                // exento
                'MV_VR_EXENTO'      => 0, 
                'MV_VR_IVA'         => $totalIvaDoc,
                'MV_VRS_IVA_1'      => $totalIvaDoc,
                'MV_CLASE_DOC'      => 'P',
                'MV_CLASE_VALOR'    => 'U',
                'MV_TIPOF'          => $tipoDocERP, 
                'MV_PORC_IVA'       => 19, 
                'MV_VRS_GRAVADO_1'  => $totalBrutoDoc, 
                'MV_CANT'           => $totalCant,
                'MV_COD_USU'        => 'CRMWEB', 
                'MV_TERMINAL'       => 'CRM', 
                'MV_TIPOP'          => $tipoDocERP,
                'MV_PEDIDO'         => $numeroPedidoERP,
                /*
                'MV_VR_RETEN'     => 0,
                'MV_VRS_RETEN_1'    => 0, 
                'MV_VR_BASE_RET_1'  => 0, */
                'MV_HORA'           => date('Gis00'), // hora con formato hhmmss00
                'MV_FCH_DIG'        => date('Ymd') 
            )
        );
```

Comment: Por lo que veo estás usando el método `create()` que recibe un arreglo con llave y valor para crear un nuevo registro, ¿no es así?, por favor agrega todo el segmento de código que involucra la problemática.

Comment: Ok ya lo edite con todo el problema

Answer (score 1):

No estás limitado a crear nuevos registros con el método `create()` en Laravel, también puedes ir agregando campo por campo individualmente, depende mucho de como tengas tus datos en la base de datos, ejemplo:

Si tus campos no tienen restricción de `not null`, es decir, permiten que agregues campos vacíos a un registro, podrías dejarlos nulos y después hacer la condición que mencionas:

```
$nuevoPedidoGenERP  = tbPedidosGenERP::create(
            array(
                'MV_TIPO'           => $tipoDocERP, 
                'MV_TIPOF'          => $tipoDocERP, 
                'MV_NUM'            => $numeroPedidoERP, 
                'MV_FACTURA'        => $numeroPedidoERP, 
                'MV_FCH'            => $fechaHoy, 
                'MV_FCH_LLEGA'      => $fechaHoy,
                 //Aquí agrega todos los campos que te sean posibles que no requieran de alguna validación, etc.
                 //...

           )
        );

if($condicion){
   //No te explicaste bien sobre los valores y nombres de los campos pero esta es la idea:
   $nuevoPedidoGenERP->exento = 'exento';
   $nuevoPedidoGenERP->save();
}
```

También, como mencioné, no estás limitado a usar el método `create()`, también puedes agregar uno por uno creando una instancia del modelo con `new`, ejemplo:

```
$nuevoPedidoGenERP  = new tbPedidosGenERP;
$nuevoPedidoGenERP->MV_TIPO = $tipoDocERP, 
$nuevoPedidoGenERP->MV_TIPOF = $tipoDocERP,
//Agregar todos los necesarios
//...
 if($condicion){
       $nuevoPedidoGenERP->exento = 'exento';

 }
$nuevoPedidoGenERP->save();
```

Comment: Para el caso de `create()`, algo que suelo hacer para evitar dejar campos nulos y después hacer hacer otra consulta a DB en un condicional, es crear el array en una variable, y en el condicional hacer un `array_merge()` con las clave/valor que correspondan. Finalmente usar `create($array)` pasándole el array completo.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Claro, también es una muy buena alternativa, casi no trabajo con `create()` pero si sería mejor hacerlo como dices para evitar muchas consultas a la BD.